# Docker Window can't mount a folder from window to container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

this is **compose file**

```
version: '2'

services:   
  finsify-postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5.4
    # init database and user
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=32014a0c
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-initdb/dump:/tmp/dump
      - ./postgres-initdb/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "3101:5432"   
  finsify-redis:
    image: redis:3.2.3
    ports:
      - "3001:6379"
```

output command :

```
...............................................
finsify-postgres_1  | waiting for server to start....LOG: database system was shut down at 2016-10-07 04:07:24 UTC 
finsify-postgres_1  | LOG: MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled 
finsify-postgres_1  | LOG: database system is ready to accept connections finsify-postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started 
finsify-postgres_1  | done 
finsify-postgres_1  | server started 
finsify-postgres_1  | ALTER ROLE 
finsify-postgres_1  | 
finsify-postgres_1  |
finsify-postgres_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
finsify-postgres_1  | 
finsify-postgres_1  | LOG: received fast shutdown request 
finsify-postgres_1  | LOG: aborting any active transactions 
finsify-postgres_1  | LOG: autovacuum launcher shutting down 
finsify-postgres_1  | LOG: shutting down 
finsify-postgres_1  | waiting for server to shut down....
finsify-postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is shut down
finsify-postgres_1  | done 
finsify-postgres_1  | server stopped ............
```

in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d , There are two bash script , they create a database and import from dump file to this database .
but it didn't work in window 10.

These script work well in MAC OS , Ubuntu , I use docker 1.12.1 .
I tried to run a other container with same config and exec to container but docker-entrypoint-initdb.d didn't include script which I written .

Thanks for help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely because you did not share the C drive where your project is located. This is need because VirtualBox is used and does not have access to your drive by default.

[image]